# Python - pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor() - pyautowindll.user32.ReleaseDC failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, pyautogui

I've been having this problem while trying to make a piano tiles bot, the first time i used this function it for some reason returns this error, and idk why

```
import pyautogui

# R G B
black = (17, 17, 17)
# x, y
box1 = (757, 815)
box2 = (885, 817)
box3 = (1010, 816)
box4 = (1135, 822)

#start game
x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Python\Python Programs\TESTING\start_black.png', region=(706, 550, 1194, 726))
pyautogui.click(x, y)

while True:
    if pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(*box1, black):
        pyautogui.click(*box1)
    elif pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(*box2, black):
        pyautogui.click(*box2)
    elif pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(*box3, black):
        pyautogui.click(*box3)
    elif pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(*box4, black):
        pyautogui.click(*box4)
```

Full Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/Utilities_and_Apps/Python/MY PROJECTS/Python/Python Programs/TESTING/tester.py", line 16, in <module>
    if pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(757, 815, black):
  File "E:\Utilities_and_Apps\Python\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 559, in pixelMatchesColor
    pix = pixel(x, y)
    return (r, g, b)
  File "E:\Utilities_and_Apps\Python\lib\contextlib.py", line 120, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "E:\Utilities_and_Apps\Python\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 113, in __win32_openDC
    raise WindowsError("windll.user32.ReleaseDC failed : return 0")
OSError: windll.user32.ReleaseDC failed : return 0
```

Comment: Did you ever work it out?